# How to plot date/time on X but display only dates in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a series of data points, each for a specific date/time. The time between each point varies, and the range covers several days (up to 30 days). There may be multiple points per day, or there may be days with no data points.

I would like the X scale to show the dates (with day of week), and for the data points to be plotted where they should go based on both the date and time of day. For instance, 2018-02-15 12:00:00 would be half-way between the labels for 02-15 and 02-16.

Here is some sample code/data:

```
var chartData = {
    type:'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
                label:'Depression',
                backgroundColor:'#00f',
                borderColor:'#00f',
                data:[
                    {y:3,t:Date.parse('2018/02/20 05:01:16')},
                    {y:4,t:Date.parse('2018/02/20 15:03:09')},
                    {y:5,t:Date.parse('2018/02/21 05:04:09')},
                    {y:1,t:Date.parse('2018/02/21 08:06:09')},
                    {y:5,t:Date.parse('2018/02/22 05:05:09')},
                ],
                fill:false,
            },
            {
                label:'Anxiety',
                backgroundColor:'#d0d',
                borderColor:'#d0d',
                data:[
                    {y:6,t:Date.parse('2018/02/20 05:01:16')},
                    {y:2,t:Date.parse('2018/02/20 15:03:09')},
                    {y:4,t:Date.parse('2018/02/21 05:04:09')},
                    {y:6,t:Date.parse('2018/02/21 08:06:09')},
                    {y:3,t:Date.parse('2018/02/22 05:05:09')},
                ],
                fill:false,
            },
            {
                label:'Activity',
                backgroundColor:'#f90',
                borderColor:'#f90',
                data:[
                    {y:4,t:Date.parse('2018/02/20 05:01:16')},
                    {y:1,t:Date.parse('2018/02/20 15:03:09')},
                    {y:4,t:Date.parse('2018/02/21 05:04:09')},
                    {y:7,t:Date.parse('2018/02/21 08:06:09')},
                    {y:3,t:Date.parse('2018/02/22 05:05:09')},
                ],
                fill:true,
            },
            {
                label:'Physical Health',
                backgroundColor:'#ffc',
                borderColor:'#cc0',
                data:[
                    {y:-2,t:Date.parse('2018/02/20 05:01:16')},
                    {y:-3,t:Date.parse('2018/02/20 15:03:09')},
                    {y:-2,t:Date.parse('2018/02/21 05:04:09')},
                    {y:-6,t:Date.parse('2018/02/21 08:06:09')},
                    {y:-5,t:Date.parse('2018/02/22 05:05:09')},
                ],
                fill:true,
            },
        ],
        fill:false,
    },
    'options': {
        responsive:true,
        title:{
            display:true,
            text:'Recent History',
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes:[{
                display:true,
                time: {
                    min:Date.parse('2018/02/01 00:00:00'),
                    max:Date.parse('2018/03/01 00:00:00'),
                    displayFormats:{
                        day:'ddd MM/DD',
                    },
                    unit:'day',
                    round:'day',
                },
                distribution:'linear',
                scaleLabel: {
                    display:true,
                    labelString:'Date'
                },
                bounds:'data',
                ticks: {
                    source:'data',
                },
            }],
            yAxes:[{
                display:true,
                scaleLabel:'Rating'
            }]
        },
    }
};
```

The code above only displays the first two data points in each series.
[image: Results Of Code In Chart.js]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#ticks-source
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#scale-title-configuration

You could try changing

```
ticks: {
   source:'data',
},
```

... to `source:'auto'` which auto-truncates tick labels for you, and just see what that looks like ...

The time-scale display format for X-axis [is described here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats), so you can format it to whatever Moment.js time format you want, e.g. `'YYYY-mm-dd`:

```
 xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    displayFormats: {
                        quarter: 'MMM YYYY'
                    }
                }
            }]
```

... Though it looks like maybe you have that in there already. Is it not showing any x-axis ticks? Is it showing any errors?

Or you could try following [this example](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#scale-title-configuration) to override the callback method for a custom 'tick' if you want to include something besides the date/time. Their example was to append a dollar sign before all the values. If you only want to deal w/date-time then the above solution ought to be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried them. Adding ```type:'time'``` caused it to take so long that the browser asked to stop the code, and it never displayed the chart. Changing 'auto' to 'data' didn't seem to make a difference. It is only displaying the first two data points, and nothing is showing up for the labels on the X axes. I'm sure I have a problem in the options.scales part, but can't find any reference example for this use case. Any other ideas?

Comment: I tried one more thing in addition to adding the type:'time' to the xAxes. I also changed the distribution to 'series', and now it seems to work! Thanks @mc01 for pointing me in the right direction!!